# underscore.js reject function not working

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Any idea why this piece of code is not working? As you see, I am trying to delete the object with id = 1 from an array.

```
var arr = [{id: 1}, {id: 2}];
    console.log('arr: ', arr);

    _.reject(arr, function(obj) {
       console.log('Deleting obj')
      return obj.id == 1;
    });
console.log('arr now : ', arr); // This displays an unchanged array
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not assigning back the result of `_.reject` to `arr`. This will work:

```
arr = _.reject(arr, function(obj) {
    console.log('Deleting obj')
    return obj.id == 1;
});
```